# Copy information from Sheet2 to Sheet1

Tags: excel

I have two sheets (sheet1 / Sheet2).  Sheet2 contains random numbers where one random is selected and I would that last number generated to be copied to last row in Sheet1 Column I

I have tried various code

```
Sub passpop()

    Dim v As Variant
    Dim strPassword As String

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        v = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Value
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Cut .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)(2)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Sheet1.Range("I13:I13") = v
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Two way to copy paste:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Paste()

    'Copy Paste with value and formatting
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")

    'Copy Paste only value
    Sheet1.Range("A2").Copy
    Sheet2.Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: make sure that you change the source (Sheet1) and the destination (Sheet2) to the sheets that you want

Comment: I have changed the Sheet  Names

Comment: i try it and i working perfectly. debug the code and ensure that is coping the right cell.

Comment: which part of code are you using ?  I have tried using the second suggestion and not working